# Json decode trouble in PHP (multiple arrays)

Tags: arrays, json

Below is the Json file stored on my server through webhook:

> [{"event":"open","email":"myemail@email.com","timestamp":1414435811,"category":["Newsletter"],"newsletter":{"newsletter_user_list_id":"18177422","newsletter_id":"3318683","newsletter_send_id":"3470425"}}]
>   [{"event":"open","email":"youremail@email.com","timestamp":1414435811,"category":["Newsletter"],"newsletter":{"newsletter_user_list_id":"18177422","newsletter_id":"3318683","newsletter_send_id":"3470425"}}]

And I want to read this file and update them into my database.  I tried to put together snippets from around the web but it's not really working... I (think I) am having trouble figuring out how to read multiple arrays.

> [{"event":"open","email":"myemail@email.com","timestamp":1414435811,"category":["Newsletter"],"newsletter":{"newsletter_user_list_id":"18177422","newsletter_id":"3318683","newsletter_send_id":"3470425"}]

To work with the example given above, when webhook.log file is only filled with the first part of the Json file, it works correctly and outputs: open myemail@email 10/27/2014 01:50:11. When I try to read more than one of the arrays, it gives me :Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead.' And since $json outputs the entire file when prompted, I am assuming "json_decode($json, TRUE)" is not doing its job. I am new to this and need some help... Thanks!

```
 $filename = "webhook.log";
 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
 $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

 $json = file_get_contents($filename);
 fclose($handle);


 $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
     new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
     RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

 foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
     if(is_array($val)) {
        // echo "$key:\n";
     } 
     else {
           if ($key!=Newsletter){
           // echo "$key => $val\n";
               if ($key==event){
                   $status=$val;
                   echo $status;
               }
               if ($key==email){
                   $email=$val;
                   echo $email;
               }
               if ($key==timestamp){
                   $date=date('m/d/Y h:i:s', $val);
                   echo $date;
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you have provided as an example is not a valid JSON string.  That is kind of a hard-stop.

You can confirm the in-validity of the JSON string [here](http://jsonlint.com/):

```
Parse error on line 15:
...5"        }    }][    {        "eve
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

What this is pointing out, specifically, is the butting of your arrays:

```
[... array data ...]
[... another array ...]
```

This is not correct syntax.  It is possible to decode multiple JSON arrays, but they would have to be housed in a parent container, and have a valid deliminator between them:

```
[
    [... array data ...],
    [... another array ...]
]
```

Where `[ ... ]` is the parent array, and the `,` is separating them.  This will provide you with an array of arrays.

Unfortunately, there is no way to parse the JSON string to make what you *have* behave correctly.  Regex is not the solution here, well, not a simple Regex anyway.  See if you can get the data in the correct form.  OR, if you get the data from two different places/calls, and write it to the file in the first place yourself, write it in the correct form.

If you are going to have a file filled with JSON Arrays, that you want to write to incrementally and read out as an Array of Arrays, try writing them as you have here, but with a `,` separating them.  When you read them out, simply wrap them with `[ ... ]` and decode.  This should give you expected results:

Write one to empty file:

```
[... json array 1 ...]
```

Write another (add a coma to the end of the existing file and append the JSON):

```
[... json array 1 ...],
[... json array 2 ...]
```

Read exactly that into a PHP string, wrapped in `[ ... ]`:

```
$file_string = $...; // the above
$json_string = "[$file_string]"; // now valid
// decode
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael I've decided to decode each Json strings as they were passed by the webhook and handled the old Json arrays as you suggested and now my database is updating properly. Thank you very much